# UPS beeping on mouse scroll or other events

Tags: power-management, ups

I have this hardware problem, my UPS battery beeps a lot when using Ubuntu (not so much on windows), so I am thinking that it may be a interrupt problem or a power surge of some sort. The strange thing is that is happening even when I do a mouse scroll, or play a video on full screen or other strange seemingly unrelated events.

Any suggestions?
I can post some configs if you think they can be useful.

Comment: You've simply overloaded your UPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU rates would jump during scroll but does this happen when you rotate the mousewheel wheel on something that doesn't scroll?

**If it doesn't** it's probably a hardware issue with the PSU or the UPS not being able to deal with the CPU changing power states. It's probably a sign that one or both is faulty or just overloaded. Testing the second is easiest: unplug a load of stuff and test again.

... But if you still get beeps aside from CPU-intensive things, I've really no idea. Some sort of interrupt crossover but again, no idea how that could happen.

Comment: is it normal for CPU intensive things? I have a dual video card with a big screen, so I guess that will be intensive and use more juice from the power supply, but I thought that the UPS is regulating the tension of the current that goes in not out.

Comment: Completely. When idle a CPU is drawing low current plus its power state means its clock is cycling at a lower rate. As soon as you do things, the cycle rate shoots up and the power consumed per cycle increases to do more work. We're only talking about short burts here but the power easily varies ±50W and that could easily knock over an already overloaded UPS.